# Unable to ping virtual machine from host

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have  installed VM Linux at my Windows10 OS. I have set IP 192.168.0.1 for my VM. Can anyone guide how to make it accessible from host?

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:0C:29:0F:5E:22
inet addr:192.168.0.1 Bcast:192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe0f:5e22/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:0 (0.0 b) TX bytes:8294 (8.0 KiB) Interrupt:67 Base address:0x2024

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1 RX packets:1465 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:1465 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:2569896 (2.4 MiB) TX bytes:2569896 (2.4 MiB)

[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: Allow that IP address of VM in Windows Firewall in host OS.

Comment: Which vitualization product (VMware etc)? What network adapter used for the VM? What's the IP of the host?